# opening a modal with the click of a button

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, modal-dialog, jsx

The next code uses a Modal react component:

```
export class AddWorkLogEditor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.addWorkLog = this.addWorkLog.bind(this);       
        this.onOpenModal = this.onOpenModal.bind(this);
        this.onCloseModal = this.onCloseModal.bind(this);
        this.state = {
             open:true

           };
      }

  onOpenModal() {
     this.setState({open: this.props.openModal});
  }

  onCloseModal() {
     this.setState({open:false});
  }

  addWorkLog() {

   }



 render() {
      const bstyle = {
         backgroundColor: 'green',
         textAlign:"left",
         paddingLeft: '0px',
         color: 'white'
    };
 const {open} = this.state;
       return (
           <div>
                <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} little>
                <h3>hi gi</h3>

                 <Button bsStyle="success" bsSize="small" onClick ={(ev) => {console.log(ev)} }> Save </Button>
                 </Modal>
            </div>
       );
    }
}
```

I am trying to call it using:

```
addWorkLog()
{
      return <AddWorkLogEditor/>;
}
```

and

```
 createAddWorkLogButton () {

    return (
        <button style={ { color: '#007a86'} } onClick={this.addWorkLog} >Add Work Log</button>
    );
 }
```

I mean, after I click at this button nothing shows up. Is there another way to call that modal? I am importing the modal from:

import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal'

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are trying to render the modal only once the button is clicked, while that's  quite natural for non-react environments, in react it works in a different way. In the simplest solution the `Modal` should be always rendered, and when a user clicks the button you change the modal `open` property to `true`.

```
{ /* all the markup of your page */ }
<button onClick={() => this.setState({showModal: true})}>Add Work Log</button>
{ /* anything else */ }

{ /* modal is here but it is hidden */ }
<Modal open={this.state.showModal}>...</Modal>
```

Alternatively, you can just skip the modal rendering at all until the `showModal` becomes true.

```
this.state.showModal && <Modal open>...</Modal>
```

Comment: I think I understand what u mean... let me try! thanks a lot!

Comment: If the `Modal` is closed how do you change the state of the showModal back to false again? I have tried to use the Modal onClose, but it's called even when confirmation button is clicked